# How uniquely identify normalize one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, normalization, database-schema

I have a database having Medication Reminders and Medication Reminders have different schedules and these schedules(two times a day) have different reminder occurrences(Dates on which reminder come) so all have one to many relationship.

```
                        |----SCHEDULE1 ----|----OCCURRENCE1

                        |----SCHEDULE1 ----|----OCCURRENCE2

MEDICATION_REMINDER --- |----SCHEDULE2 ----|----OCCURRENCE1

                        |----SCHEDULE2 ----|----OCCURRENCE2
```

Now I can store these values like

MEDICATION_REMINDER(MEDICATION_REMINDER_ID,OTHER_DETAILS)

SCHEDULE(MEDICATION_REMINDER_ID_FK,SCHEDULE_ID,TIMES) //PK is MEDICATION_REMINDER_ID_FK,SCHEDULE_ID

OCCURRENCE(SCHEDULE_ID_FK,OCCURRENCE_ID,DATE_TIME)  //NO PRIMARY KEY AS OF NOW

Now Occurrence cant be identified uniquely 
for eg

> M1 and M2 has two schedules  S1 (7:00 AM) and S2 (8:00 PM) and S1 has three
>   occurrences say o1 ,o2 ,o3 and S2 also has three occurrences say o1
>   ,o2 ,o3

Now my table is

```
MEDICATION_REMINDER
_____________________
M1
M2
_____________________

SCHEDULE
__________________
M1   S1    7:00AM
M1   S2    8:00PM
M2   S1    7:00AM
M2   S2    8:00PM
__________________


OCCURRENCE
__________________
S1    O1   21-04-13 7:00AM
S1    O2   22-04-13 7:00AM
S1    O3   23-04-13 7:00AM
S2    O1   21-04-13 9:00PM
S2    O2   22-04-13 9:00PM
S2    O3   23-04-13 9:00PM

S1    O1   21-04-13 7:00AM
S1    O2   22-04-13 7:00AM
S1    O3   23-04-13 7:00AM
S2    O1   21-04-13 9:00PM
S2    O2   22-04-13 9:00PM
S2    O3   23-04-13 9:00PM

__________________
```

How to uniquely identify occurrence table rows.Is it good to store MEDICATION_REMINDER_ID in OCCURRENCE table. I do not want to do that because OCCURRENCE table and MEDICATION_REMINDER
do not have direct relationship.Please help me 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While MEDICATION_REMINDER and OCCURRENCE do not have a direct relationship, OCCURRENCE has a direct relationship with SCHEDULE. The primary key for SCHEDULE is MEDICATION_REMINDER_ID, SCHEDULE_ID, so to establish the relationship between SCHEDULE and OCCURRENCE, you need to have a foreign key relationship between the two tables. This implies that the primary key of SCHEDULE has to be shown in OCCURRENCE, so MEDICATION_REMINDER_ID needs to be included in OCCURRENCE. This also provides the means to uniquely identify the OCCURRENCE instance.